# Android autobahn version 0.5.2

Tags: android, autobahn

I want to use autobahn socket with subscribe functionality. It is available from version 0.5.2 within WampConnection class but on official website I can only find version 0.5.0 for download.

How can I use 0.5.2 version or subscribe functionality in autobahn?

I want to use autobahn library because backend is also using this library.

Thanks

Comment: check version in git https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-android, if it is 0.5.2. or here https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-android/releases/tag/v0.5.2

Comment: And how can I import it into my project? As I can see, these are all eclipse developed projects (demos and autobahn 0.5.2)

Comment: if you use Android Studio try - File > new > Import module. and add this module as dependency